# Resolving minFactor error when using nls in R

Tags: r, nls, non-linear-regression

I am running nls models in R on several different datasets, using the self-starting Weibull Growth Curve function, e.g.

```
MOD <- nls(Response ~ SSweibull(Time, Asym, Drop, lrc, pwr), data = DATA)
```

With data like this, it works as expected:

```
GOOD.DATA <- data.frame("Time" = c(1:150), "Response" = c(31.2, 20.0, 44.3, 35.2, 
31.4, 27.5, 24.1, 25.9, 23.3, 21.2, 21.3, 19.8, 18.4, 17.3, 16.3, 16.3,
16.6, 15.9, 15.9, 15.8, 15.1, 15.6, 15.1, 14.5, 14.2, 14.2, 13.7, 14.1,
13.7, 13.4, 13.0, 12.6, 12.3, 12.0, 11.7, 11.4, 11.1, 11.0, 10.8, 10.6,
10.4, 10.1, 11.6, 12.0, 11.9, 11.7, 11.5, 11.2, 11.5, 11.3, 11.1, 10.9,
10.9, 11.4, 11.2, 11.1, 10.9, 10.9, 10.7, 10.7, 10.5, 10.4, 10.4, 10.3,
10.1, 10.0, 9.9, 9.7, 9.6, 9.7, 9.6, 9.5, 9.5, 9.4, 9.3, 9.2, 9.1, 9.0,
8.9, 9.0, 8.9, 8.8, 8.8, 8.7, 8.6, 8.5, 8.4, 8.3, 8.3, 8.2, 8.1, 8.0,
8.0, 8.0, 7.9, 7.9, 7.8, 7.7, 7.6, 7.6, 7.6, 7.6, 7.5, 7.5, 7.5, 7.5,
7.4, 7.4, 7.3, 7.2, 7.2, 7.1, 7.1, 7.0, 7.0, 6.9, 6.9, 6.8, 6.8, 6.7,
6.7, 6.6, 6.6, 6.5, 6.5, 6.4, 6.4, 6.4, 6.3, 6.3, 6.2, 6.2, 6.2, 6.1 
6.1, 6.1, 6.0, 6.0, 5.9, 5.9, 5.9, 5.9, 5.8, 5.8, 5.8, 5.8, 5.8, 5.8,
5.8, 5.7))
```

But with this data set:

```
BAD.DATA <- data.frame("Time" = c(1:150), "Response" = c(89.8, 67.0, 
51.4, 41.2, 39.4, 38.5, 34.3, 30.9, 29.9, 34.8, 32.5, 30.1, 28.5, 27.0,
26.2, 24.7, 23.8, 23.6, 22.6, 22.0, 21.3, 20.7, 20.1, 19.6, 19.0, 18.4,
17.9, 17.5, 17.1, 23.1, 22.4, 21.9, 23.8, 23.2, 22.6, 22.0, 21.6, 21.1,
20.6, 20.1, 19.7, 19.3, 19.0, 19.2, 18.8, 18.5, 18.3, 19.5, 19.1, 18.7,
18.5, 18.3, 18.0, 17.7, 17.5, 17.3, 17.0, 16.7, 16.7, 16.9, 16.6, 16.4,
16.1, 15.9, 15.8, 15.6, 15.4, 15.2, 15.0, 14.8, 14.7, 14.5, 14.4, 14.2,
14.0, 13.9, 13.7, 13.6, 15.4, 15.2, 15.1, 15.0, 14.9, 14.7, 14.6, 14.5,
14.4, 14.3, 14.4, 14.2, 14.1, 14.0, 13.8, 13.7, 13.6, 13.5, 13.4, 13.2,
13.3, 13.2, 13.1, 13.0, 12.9, 12.8, 12.7, 12.6, 12.5, 12.5, 12.4, 12.3,
12.2, 12.1, 12.1, 11.9, 12.8, 12.7, 12.6, 12.5, 12.4, 14.2, 14.1, 14.0,
14.1, 14.0, 13.9, 13.8, 13.7, 13.7, 13.6, 13.5, 13.4, 13.3, 13.3, 13.2,
13.1, 13.0, 12.9, 12.9, 12.8, 12.7, 12.6, 12.9, 12.8, 12.7, 12.6, 12.5,
12.5, 12.4, 12.3, 12.2))
```

I get the error;

```
Error in nls(y ~ cbind(1, -exp(-exp(lrc) * x^pwr)), data = xy, algorithm = "plinear",
  : step factor 0.000488281 reduced below 'minFactor' of 0.000976562
```

By including the `control` argument I am able to change the `minFactor` for `GOOD.DATA`:

```
MOD <- nls(Response ~ SSweibull(Time, Asym, Drop, lrc, pwr), data = GOOD.DATA, 
control = nls.control(minFactor = 1/4096))
```

But the model was running without errors anyway. With `BAD.DATA` and several other datasets, including `control` has no effect and I just get the same error message.

---

**Questions**

1. How can I change the `minFactor` for the `BAD.DATA`?
2. What's causing the error? (i.e. what is it about the data set that triggers the error?)
3. Will changing the `minFactor` resolve this error, or is this one of R's obscure error messages and it actually indicates a different issue?

Answer (score 2):

It seems the `control` option does not work in your case, since the code breaks at `getInitial` while self-starting, that is, before using your provided `control` parameters. One way would be to try specifying some starting parameters, instead of the naive self-starting. For `nls` it is often the case that playing with the initial parameters will make-or-break it, not entirely sure for the specific Weibull case though, but should be the same.

To see that you don't arrive to the actual `control`, you can try with `nls.control(printEval = T)` and see that there's no print.

Comment: Thanks for this. At least it's good to understand why the `minFactor` argument was being ignored. I opted for the self-start model _because_ I was struggling to find reasonable start values. It is so sensitive to the start values that I end up with the same error, even once I've increased the `maxiter` to 10,000.

Comment: For the future, in many cases trying ``debugonce()``, i.e., ``debugonce(nls)``, and seeing what happens inside the code is a good start to see why something doesn't work